# Saving a success message with multiple forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two forms, where a user can change his name and change his password. I am having difficulty of saving a 'success message' based upon which field is saved. This is what I currently have --

```
def account(request):
    message = '' ###
    change_name_form = ChangeNameForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    change_password_form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST or None, user = request.user)
    if "change_name" in request.POST and change_name_form.is_valid():
        change_name_form.save()
        message = 'Your name has been changed.' ###
        return redirect('.')
    if "change_password" in request.POST and change_password_form.is_valid():
        change_password_form.save()
        message = 'Your password has been changed.' ###
        return redirect('.')
    return render_to_response('userprofile/account.html',{'message': message,...})
```

How would I go about saving a different message based upon which form is filled out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the redirects, and make sure to check for POST, generally you only handle the form processing if it's a POST request. Make sure the pass the forms to the template.

```
def account(request):
    message = ''
    change_name_form = ChangeNameForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    change_password_form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST or None, user = request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "change_name" in request.POST and change_name_form.is_valid():
            change_name_form.save()
            message = 'Your name has been changed.' ###
        if "change_password" in request.POST and change_password_form.is_valid():
            change_password_form.save()
            message = 'Your password has been changed.' ###
    return render_to_response('userprofile/account.html',{'message': message,...})
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using Django's built in messaging framework. It's useful for exactly this sort of stuff:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

```
from django.contrib import messages
def account(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        cnf = ChangeNameForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        cpf = ChangePasswordForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if cnf.is_valid() and (request.user.username != cnf.cleaned_data['username']):
            cnf.save()
            messages.info(request, "Username Changed")
        if cpf.is_valid() and (request.user.password != cpf.cleaned_data['username']):
            cpf.save()
            messages.info(request, "Password Changed")
    else:
        cnf = ChangeNameForm(instance=request.user)
        cpf = ChangePasswordForm(instance=request.user)
    ...
```

**template**

```
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```